# SharePoint 2013 anonymous access

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, csom

How can I add anonymous access to list using CSOM. In Server-Side Object Model I can use AnonymousPermMask64, but how it can be implemented using CSOM?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use it in SharePoint App, try like this.

```
string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(siteUri);

//Get the access token for the URL.  
//Requires this app to be registered with the tenant
string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(
    TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, 
    siteUri.Authority, 
    realm).AccessToken;

//Get client context with access token
using(var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(
     siteUri.ToString(),accessToken))
{
    //Do work here
}
```

References: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/10/24/what-every-developer-needs-to-know-about-sharepoint-apps-csom-and-anonymous-publishing-sites/

For Token Helper: https://github.com/OfficeDev/SharePoint-Add-in-CSOM-BasicDataOperations/blob/master/SharePoint-Add-in-CSOM-BasicDataOperationsWeb/TokenHelper.cs